# Where is ".htaccess" apache file located in Linux Red Hat?

Tags: apache, redhat

Does anyone know where is the .htaccess file located after I install in linux red hat 5?

Comment: Would this be a better question for ServerFault?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no .htaccess file that's installed.  You will have a global config file for Apache, which is in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf on RedHat (see http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Reference_Guide/s1-apache-config.html).  On the other hand, .htaccess files are something you create on a per-directory basis where the actual web files live.